# How to write multiple sub-query in Hibernate criteria

Tags: oracle, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I am trying to write oracle subquery in Hibernate criteria but unable to do it. Can anyone help me to achieve this. Below is my oracle query.

```
SELECT a.id,
  b.address
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN TABLE b
ON a.id       = b.id
WHERE mainId IN
  (SELECT bp.ptyID
  FROM bpTable bp,
    busHeaderbh bh
  WHERE bh.aid      = bp.aid
  AND bh.parentBID IN
    (SELECT bp.ptyID
    FROM bpTable bp,
      busHeaderbh bh
    WHERE bh.aid     = bp.aid
    AND bh.parentBID = 123
    UNION
    SELECT 123 FROM dual
    )
  UNION
  SELECT 123 FROM dual
  )
AND
GROUP BY a.id,
  b.credttm
ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have written one example for one to many relationship table
you can get reference from it

```
Criteria person = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class).createAlias("personId", "personId");

person.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.ilike("PersonFirstname",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.prop1",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.col1",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.addOrder(Property.forName("colName").desc()
.addOrder(Property.forName("colName").asc());
```

Comment: Thanks Malay... I will try in some time and let you know.